# The relation between the probability of a particle to the left or right and the potential

Tags: physics

For example, if the potential is a harmonic potential $V(x)=kx^2$.

How to calculate the probability to the left or right when the particle stays at the position $x_0$?. Here $x_0$ is a constant.

Comment: The probability is zero. A think you mean  probability density. For the well known harmonic oscillator you can e.g. look it up at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#:~:text=The%20quantum%20harmonic%20oscillator%20is,model%20systems%20in%20quantum%20mechanics.

Comment: @Daniel Huber   What I mean is not in the sense of mean probability. I want to simulate a  particle in a harmonic potential. But I do not know how to calculate the probability to the left  or right.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The probability density is given by $\lvert \psi\rvert^2$, where $\psi$ denotes the wave function. Thus to find the probability to the right or left of a point $x_0$ you need to integrate $\int_{x_0}^{\pm \infty} \lvert \psi\rvert^2$. The link @Daniel Huber provided explains how to find the wave function from the potential, i.e. solving Schrodinger's equation.